# How to extract words containing combinations of certain characters in R

Tags: r, regex

In this sample text:

```
turns <- tolower(c("Does him good to stir him up now and again .", 
           "When , when I see him he w's on the settees .",
           "Yes it 's been eery for a long time .",
           "blissful timing , indeed it was "))
```

I'd like to extract all words that contain the letters `y` **and** `e` no matter what position or combination, namely `yes`and `eery`, using `str_extract` from `stringr`:

This regex, in which I determine that `y` occur immediately before `e`, matches not surprisingly only `yes` but not `eery`:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(turns, "\\b([a-z]+)?ye([a-z]+)?\\b"))
[1] "yes"
```

Putting `y`and `e` into a character class doesn't get me the desired result either in that all words **either** with `y` **or** with `e` are matched:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(turns, "\\b([a-z]+)?[ye]([a-z]+)?\\b")) 
 [1] "does"    "when"    "when"    "see"     "he"      "the"     "settees" "yes"     "been"    "eery"    "time"    "indeed"
```

So what **is** the right solution?

Comment: Use `"\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use both base R and `stringr` approaches:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(turns, "\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b")
regmatches(turns, gregexpr("\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b", turns, perl=TRUE))
```

Or, without turning the strings to lower case, you may use a case insensitive matching with `(?i)`:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(turns, "(?i)\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b")
regmatches(turns, gregexpr("\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b", turns, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH9gVl/1) and the [R demo](https://tio.run/##jY9BS8QwEIXv/RWPXmy07g9YXLzoQfAkigiFJW1n00CalElKdxF/e51WZREv5pLHe/O9SXie08g@4uYaKbgwERdNkd8FiuhsDxNCKwFisrwa4wAfJmjfQhttPTZ5iQznk7925FFiWq4HRKKV6wjTRUTwSCIjpUSyQuBf7Jt4NkEGaxKciE84BIaGC94g2Z7@MLWzMR5Gt6RWhkpY3xK1S9GkI3KlsiyLiSXk7VbEno6JdZP22rli/X6JvKrq4nZXVcP748flSZ01qS9xJRO5VDGZXqemo/jDGrHoOHDxz5IS3@BA7HbPTy/38mbjA9Om0ZFWR6l5/gQ). Also, if you want to make it a tiny bit more efficient, you may use principle of contrast in the lookahead patterns: match any letters but `y` in the first and all letters but the `e` in the second using character class substraction:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(turns, "(?i)\\b(?=[\\p{L}--[y]]*y)(?=[\\p{L}--[e]]*e)\\p{L}+\\b")
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\p{L}*y)` - after 0 or more Unicode letters, there must be `y` (`[\p{L}--[y]]*` matches any 0 or more letters but `y` up to the first `y`)
- `(?=\p{L}*e)` - after 0 or more Unicode letters, there must be `e` (`[\p{L}--[e]]*` matches any 0 or more letters but `e` up to the first `e`)
- `\p{L}+` - 1 or more Unicode letters
- `\b` - word boundary

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no urgent need to use `stringr::str_extract` you can get *words containing the letters y and e* in *base* with `strsplit` and `grepl` like:

```
tt <- unlist(strsplit(turns, " "))
tt[grepl("y", tt) & grepl("e", tt)]
#[1] "yes"  "eery"
```

In case you have letter chunks between words:

```
turns <- c("yes no ay ae 012y345e year.")
tt <- regmatches(turns, gregexpr("\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b", turns))[[1]]
tt[grepl("y", tt) & grepl("e", tt)]
#[1] "yes"  "year"
```

Comment: With `str_extract`, *words* proper can be extracted, i.e. letter chunks between word boundaries. With `tt <- unlist(strsplit(turns, " "))
tt[grepl("y", tt) & grepl("e", tt)]`, you will also get `012y345e` like strings in the results, and although in this case it might not be an issue, in a general case, that can mess up the final output.

Comment: However, all words with punctuation after will be filtered. In a regular sentence, there will be a lot of occurrences (e.g. [`It's a dyke.`](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDsIgEEX3PcXIQkFbD0A0XZt4A8AGK6lE0hCYJjbGsyO1btTdn/f/zPyQEg6hj7CroKXkgKsIGi7jzWwJKxAnPvTORqQRQ/TOIn0vlECAsCkiFl0w3lEiToJr56@aK0VKQGSwhI83/gIzA1Xks7bvAudZNOaOQbfYaOfoX538ktaWSXmm9V5I6R/HZ1WJUan1yL6QyciwedzkPGEpvQA))

Comment: Yes again - sorry. And thanks for the helpful comments! I hope it works now.

Comment: Yes, but it is already just coming to what I have, though in base R way. My solution in base R will look like `regmatches(turns, gregexpr("\\b(?=\\p{L}*y)(?=\\p{L}*e)\\p{L}+\\b", turns, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))`